# How to send a message to a specific channel

Tags: javascript, bots, channel, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel with my Discord bot, which is in several servers. I want the bot to pick up on a message from one server and send a message to my personal server, in a specific channel, but I can't get it to 'find' the channel. Has the API changed or something? I tried `npm install discord.js` to update too.

Code:

```
if (message.author.id == 'XXXXX' && !mess.includes("Dank") && message.channel.id != 'XXXXX') {
  bot.channels.get('XXXXX').send('memes');
}
```

I tried a few things but none worked.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at decideIfMention (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\bot.js:80:45)
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\bot.js:68:3)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding Crud\Discord Bot 2\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

Comment: The issue is just as it says, `.send()` is undefined. I would suggest debugging, first try and see if all your node modules are actually loaded. Then, I would suggest actually somehow logging the value of `.send`.

Comment: Assuming you have the `client` try doing `const channel = client.channels.find('name', channelName)` and then `channel.send(message)`

Comment: @GMaiolo I didn't want to have to resort to using that because in the situation that two channels with the same name are created it would likely glitch out, although I believe there is a way to specify the "guild." Either way, I'll try it when the discord servers get back online. >.<

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you have the [`client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) (which would be an instance of [`Discord.Client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)) try finding the desired channel by using [`Client.find`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find):

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === channelName)
channel.send(message)
```

If you don't have the `client` directly but have a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) instance, you could always access it from within the [Message.client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) property.

Comment: Currently getting this error  `Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Channel'.`

Comment: you need a `TextChannel` to have send.

Answer (score 17):

Well, if you have the "`client`" instance of `Discord.Client()`, then use this:

**SOLUTION UPDATED** to work with newer discordjs versions

`` client.channels.cache.get(`channelID`).send(`Text`) ``

Don't forget the channeID parameter is a string type, not number. It's really simple yet precise.

Comment: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Channel'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 13):

If you are using typescript, it will need to make a type cast on Channel. So you can transform it in TextChannel and send the messages

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'compras');

if (channel.isText() {
    (<TextChannel> channel).send('message')
}
```

Comment: Do you need to cast it? Isn't `isText()` a type guard? All types that this guard checks implement the `send` function.

Comment: @Gibbo Correct. The cast is unnecessary. `const channel = client.channels.cache.get('xxxx')
if (channel?.isText()) {
  channel.send(/* ... */)
}`

Comment: In my case, even using isText I was receiving a error saying that channel don't have send. The only way that worked was using a cast :(