# How to get URL's HTML

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to retrieve a URL's HTML content into a string so that I can use `str.search('XXX')` and if XXX is there I will perform an action.

```js
     if (fetch("https://steamcommunity.com/id/" + message.channel.lastMessage)
                        .then(res => res.text())
                        .then(body => console.log(body))
                                    // I NEED TO TRANSFORM THE HTML INTO STRING AND USE str.search('The specified profile could not be found.'))

                {
                    message.channel.lastMessage.edit('URL "' + message.channel.lastMessage + '" is not taken.')
                }


    else {return}
```

This is what I have currently, any other option to achieve the same thing is welcome.

Edit 2:

I ran the code replacing res.text() with console.log(res) as someone suggested and this is the output:

```
$ node index.js
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: Gunzip {
      _writeState: [Uint32Array],
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _transformState: [Object],
      _hadError: false,
      bytesWritten: 0,
      _handle: [Zlib],
      _outBuffer: <Buffer 88 e2 7c 69 2e 7f 00 00 e0 35 f4 02 00 00 00 00 b0 d8 eb 02 00 00 00 00 b0 d8 eb 02 00 00 00 00 67 22 2c 20 22 73 68 61 72 64 73 22 3a 20 31 2c 20 22 ... 16334 more bytes>,
      _outOffset: 0,
      _chunkSize: 16384,
      _defaultFlushFlag: 2,
      _finishFlushFlag: 2,
      _nextFlush: -1,
      _defaultFullFlushFlag: 3,
      _info: undefined,
      _level: -1,
      _strategy: 0
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120073/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
undefined
```

This isn't the entire HTML body, but it tells me the status of the page so if I can find a way to perform an action when the status is 404 that would be the same thing I was trying to achieve.

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(body)`

Comment: nevermind the '{' error i just forgot to insert a {. 

The console doesn't output anything :/

Comment: what about `console.log(res)` instead of `res.text()`?

Comment: sorry for the late reply - it now gives me a bunch of information about the given url. I thought the status of the page would be 404 when the profile doesn't exist but it's still 200. So this gives me info about the page but still no html body.