# How to make a Discord bot send text to a specific channel in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
    const specChan = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'general');
    if (message.content === '1') {
        
        message.specChan.send("2")
    }
    
});
```

I can't figure how to send a message to a channel (general). If someone says 1 it will send to a channel (general) the message 2.

Comment: It might help to use the search first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120073/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel If you are getting stuck at some point the community is happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
let channelVar = bot.guilds.cache.get('Guild-ID').channels.cache.get('Channel-ID');
channelVar.send("Hello World");
```

Comment: how would i make it to where it could respond in the same channel as them without replying/pinging?

Comment: @rubypython If I am understanding you it's with `message.channel.send("Hello World!")` like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437818/13436381

Answer (score 0):

Use message.channel.send

```
client.on("message", msg => {
   if (msg.content === "!respond") {
      msg.channel.send("Hello there!");
    };
});
```

Comment: oh ok well i watched tutorials but logs said to define "send" and "channel", because ive tried before, didnt work before but thanks

Comment: @rubypython `message.specChan.send` is **not at all** how you use variables. `message.specChan` tries to access a property of `message` named `specChan` which is total nonsense, there is no such property. if you already have a channel `specChan`, then you can just call `specChan.send("2")`

Comment: @rubypython your logs most likely said `cannot access property "send" of undefined` or `message.specChan.send is not a function` or something, issues which all arise from misuse of variable names

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of that specific channel, you can check for it by doing
`if (message.channel.id != "generalChannelID")`

So the code would look like this

```js
client.on("message", message => {
   if (message.content === "1" $$ (message.channel.id != "generalChannelID")) {
      message.channel.send("2");
    };
});
```