# Discord js message sending to specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

first off all, i know there are similar threads, but i can't find a single one that uses the same method as i would like. My code:

```
            ticketChannel.send({
                embeds: supportEmbed, 
                components: new MessageActionRow().addComponent(supportButton).addComponent(claimButton),
                message.ticketChannel.send("<@&874175844422135808> Prosím o vyřešení ticketu"); 
            })
```

The last line should send a message that pings a role with that id. Well, it doesn't. The message must be sent to the *ticketChannel* channel.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a message to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120073/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

Comment: No it does not. I have no error in console unlike that one

Comment: Does the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929491/5844241) to that question answer your question?

Comment: Have you defined `ticketChannel`? If so, can you include it in your your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to always send it to a specific channel, you'll need to use the id of the channel to define it like so: (assuming you have guild defined)

```js
let channelid = "your channel id"
let ticketchannel = guild.channels.fetch(channelid)
ticketchannel.send("<@&874175844422135808> Prosím o vyřešení ticketu")
```